# Is it incorrect to say "The song sold a copy"?

Tags: meaning

Is it not incorrect to say "The song sold a copy," for example. A copy of what?
 And how does a song sell anything? It's just a song.

Here are two examples I found on two different Wikipedia pages. I was just wondering if this was an error or not. I see it very frequently.

> -Ammar Malik songs have sold over 50 million copies worldwide in total.
>
> -By 1997, the song had sold 11 million copies.

Comment: Just look up *copy* in a dictionary.

Comment: But how does a song sell anything? "He sold 50 million copies of his song" makes sense to me, but not "The song which was his sold 50 million copies."

Comment: The book sold x copies. It's a way to avoid: By 1997, 11 million copies of the song had been sold. It avoids the passive tense and is widely used.

Comment: Your aim is to avoid ambiguity. You can say "The song sold one copy".

Comment: The term "song xxx sold nnn copies" is idiomatic for the situation where nnn copies of the song (presumably as an audio recording of some sort) were sold.  As to "correct" or "incorrect", that horse left the barn decades ago.

Comment: There's an expression "this product sells itself", which means it is sufficiently good or desirable that people will buy it as a result of simply being exposed to it.  The song or book sells copies because people see or hear it and like it, and decide on their own to purchase it.

Answer (score 2):

> A copy of what?

A copy of itself:

> **copy**
>   A single specimen of a particular book, record, or other publication or issue.
>   *‘the record has sold more than a million copies’*   https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/copy

---

> And how does a song sell anything?

It does not sell anything. It just sells. One of the meanings of ***sell*** is:

> To be purchased in (a certain quantity); achieve sales of: *a book that
>   sold a million copies*.
>   [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sell)

Another example:

> **[bestseller](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bestseller)**
>   A book or other product that sells in very large numbers.
>   *‘her autobiography is an international bestseller’*